# Set location of mouse

Tags: c#, position, cursor

I cannot  fix my mistake : /

`if (Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y)`

I have an error on `x,y`, and I want to change to `50,99` for example

Comment: `if (Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y)` in an `if` you need to use `==` . To set it would be ok, given x and y are set correctly, as needed, and, of course, without the `if`..

Comment: Thank's you ;) i have a other error :/ http://prntscr.com/7zjq3l please help me

Comment: Look the screen please http://prntscr.com/7zjqne thank's for help ;)

Comment: you forget to complete ')'
if (Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y))

Comment: You have to add one more paranthesis after Point(x, y) to close the if condition.

Comment: oh yeah excuse me /: thank's you ;)

Comment: It being only about typos, you ought to delete the question..

Comment: The code not work , when i click on the location , its do nothing : /

Comment: you need to post your code and explain what is your problem and what is your goal not just saying my code does not work.

Comment: if (Cursor.Position == new Point(212, 48))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }

Comment: _i click on the location , its do nothing_  Well, chances to hit a single point are really slim! Try:  `if ( new Rectangle(211, 480, 6,6).Contains(Cursor.Position))...`

Comment: if ( new Rectangle(211, 480, 6,6).Contains(Cursor.Position)) this code not work

Comment: Please don't post fake code

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should trig mouseClick event. It's quite simple:

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
```

Then you should handle the event. Suppose your desired position is (x,y)=(100,100):

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int xDesired = 100;
        int yDesired = 100;
        if (e.X == xDesired && e.Y == yDesired)
            MessageBox.Show("Certain point clicked.");
    }
```

Comment: First of all, Could you tell me what exactly do you want to do?
Sorry for delay.

Comment: I want when we click a certain area of ​​the form , I want there is a message that appears , Thank's ;)

Comment: 1. How can you assure that you clicked the certain position?

Comment: Do you know how to handle an event in c#?